# Probability density function maximum area under the curve

Tags: density-function

For a probability density function with min and max limits on $x$, Is it correct to say that the area under the curve between those limits must equal $1$?

E.g. $f(x) = kx^2 \quad 0 \le x \le 1$

So $k$ must be set to a value to ensure the area is $1$?

Comment: The area under the graph of a probability density function must be one, yes.

Comment: Is the question settled for you, Bryon?

Comment: Sure is. thank you. I was just looking for confirmation of my understanding.

Comment: OK. For future reference, it's nice to acknowledge helpful comments & answers.

Comment: Of course. I hadn’t got around to it - finishing up my assignment. Thanks very much